# How to fix "Google Chrome did not shutdown properly" in Windows 8.1

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, application-shutdown, system-shutdown

When shutting down Windows 8.1, Google Chrome produces the error message "Google Chrome did not shutdown properly".  How can I get Chrome to shut down without giving me that error message?

I don't have to be logged in as a Google user.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/697618/getting-google-chrome-didnt-shut-down-correctly-every-week

Answer (score 19):

There is another alternative, you just need to go to:

```
Settings
  Advanced Settings
    System
```

And uncheck the **Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed** option.

For now that is the best solution I have found that does not require you to delete your profile.

Comment: Look at the entry starting with "Received this error and found ...". It has fewer votes but contains a better solution.

Answer (score 7):

Received this error and found that the %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences file had the System, Hidden and Read-only bits set. Used attrib to remove them. The first opening of Google Chrome after stated the same message, but subsequent opening the issue was resolved.

On this system, it appears to have been caused by the installation of the Audible Manager from Audible.com.

Comment: Interesting - I also just installed Audible Manager from Audible.com and then this started happening.

Comment: Mine was also read-only, system, hidden. I only removed read-only. I had also installed Audible recently.

Answer (score 0):

In the section Users there is an option to "Delete this user", click the button, confirm that you want to delete the user and presto, Chrome stops producing the error message when you start it.

This is a fix for people who wants to use the browser without a user profile. As a little note I have noticed that Chrome seems to be slightly slower booting, but for me it's well worth it to get rid of the error message.